# URL encoding issue in email campaigns

Tags: email, url-encoding, sitefinity

## BACKGROUND:

`Sitefinity CMS` for my specific problem, but could be general too.

I have an email message which has an unsubscribe link in it like this:

```
To Unsubscribe: Click or copy paste the following link in your browser.

https://www.domain.com/unsubscribe?mailingList={|MailingList.Title|}&SubscriptionEmail={|Subscriber.Email|}
```

`{|MailingList.Title|}` and `{|Subscriber.Email|}` are `sitefinity CMS` subscriber fields. When I send out an email these two fields resolve to their respective values. Hence, the URL I get in an email is as following for example.

https://www.domain.com/unsubscribe?mailingList=mymailingList&subscriptionEmail=abc@xyz.com

The user can click on it and unsubscribe from the mailing list.

## My Problem:

If the mailing list name has a space in it, the link that appears on the email is broken at the first occurance of the space(link the link shown below breaks immediately `=my`) and hence clicking it is like clicking a invalid URL.

https://www.domain.com/unsubscribe?mailingList=my mailing List&subscriptionEmail=abc@xyz.com

I dont understand why the space in the URL doesnt resolve to a `%20`.

## My Trial:

I changed the order of the querystrings to see if it works(mailinglist was the last string originally, I put it in the middle)

I am fine if the URL does not get resolved into a link at all, just forcing the users to copy paste the entire URL. But, I was not able to do it as well.

I have read in microsoft forums that OUTLOOK resolves the spacing issue, when the URL is surrounded by `<` and `>` like this :

URL here:

But the URL doesnt even show up in the email just like it is not showing up here above this line.

Tested on OUTLOOK, GMAIL, YAHOOMAIL, MICROSOFT MAIL. The link is broken in all email clients.

Any suggestions on what is the best solution for this?